# Advanced jQuery "Sticky Bottom" and also Scrolling Sidebar Issue

Tags: jquery, scroll, fixed, sidebar, sticky

Having searched everywhere for a solution to this problem, and attempting to use a few plugins like jQuery Way-points, to no degree of success, I hope that someone here will be able to offer a solution to this.

As it is a bit complex to explain with just text I have created a diagram of the behavior.

See this link as the spam filter will not let me post and image yet:

[image: http://imgur.com/VtrQg]

All elements are of a variable height depending on the content.

1. Having a sidebar which is much shorter than the page content,
2. Once the bottom of the sidebar div enters the viewport,
3. It will stay fixed in that position while the rest of the content will continue to scroll as normal.
4. Until the sidebar reaches the footer where it will scroll upwards with the footer as normal.

This would also work in reverse as the user scrolls in the opposite direction to the top of the page.

Comment: Maybe you know of a site that does something similar to what you want so people could see it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David, but unfortunately I have never seen a site that works like this.  I am sure there must be one out there but I was not able to find one to reverse engineer.

Comment: The pictures make it oh so clear! +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/GPX3S/3/) is my solution. You can use this example and implement your own solution to your problem.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    header
</div>
<div id="left">
    Donec placerat. Nullam nibh dolor, blandit sed, fermentum id, imperdiet sit amet, neque. Nam mollis ultrices justo. Sed tempor. Sed vitae tellus. Etiam sem arcu, eleifend sit amet, gravida eget, porta at, wisi. Nam non lacus vitae ipsum viverra pretium. Phasellus massa. Fusce magna sem, gravida in, feugiat ac, molestie eget, wisi. Fusce consectetuer luctus ipsum. Vestibulum nunc. Suspendisse dignissim adipiscing libero. Integer leo. Sed pharetra ligula a dui. Quisque ipsum nibh, ullamcorper eget, pulvinar sed, posuere vitae, nulla. Sed varius nibh ut lacus. Curabitur fringilla. Nunc est ipsum, pretium quis, dapibus sed, varius non, lectus. Proin a quam. Praesent lacinia, eros quis aliquam porttitor, urna lacus volutpat urna, ut fermentum neque mi egestas dolor.
    Donec placerat. Nullam nibh dolor, blandit sed, fermentum id, imperdiet sit amet, neque. Nam mollis ultrices justo. Sed tempor. Sed vitae tellus. Etiam sem arcu, eleifend sit amet, gravida eget, porta at, wisi. Nam non lacus vitae ipsum viverra pretium. Phasellus massa. Fusce magna sem, gravida in, feugiat ac, molestie eget, wisi. Fusce consectetuer luctus ipsum. Vestibulum nunc. Suspendisse dignissim adipiscing libero. Integer leo. Sed pharetra ligula a dui. Quisque ipsum nibh, ullamcorper eget, pulvinar sed, posuere vitae, nulla. Sed varius nibh ut lacus. Curabitur fringilla. Nunc est ipsum, pretium quis, dapibus sed, varius non, lectus. Proin a quam. Praesent lacinia, eros quis aliquam porttitor, urna lacus volutpat urna, ut fermentum neque mi egestas dolor.Donec placerat. Nullam nibh dolor, blandit sed, fermentum id, imperdiet sit amet, neque. Nam mollis ultrices justo. Sed tempor. Sed vitae tellus. Etiam sem arcu, eleifend sit amet, gravida eget, porta at, wisi. Nam non lacus vitae ipsum viverra pretium. Phasellus massa. Fusce magna sem, gravida in, feugiat ac, molestie eget, wisi. Fusce consectetuer luctus ipsum. Vestibulum nunc. Suspendisse dignissim adipiscing libero. Integer leo. Sed pharetra ligula a dui. Quisque ipsum nibh, ullamcorper eget, pulvinar sed, posuere vitae, nulla. Sed varius nibh ut lacus. Curabitur fringilla. Nunc est ipsum, pretium quis, dapibus sed, varius non, lectus. Proin a quam. Praesent lacinia, eros quis aliquam porttitor, urna lacus volutpat urna, ut fermentum neque mi egestas dolor.Donec placerat. Nullam nibh dolor, blandit sed, fermentum id, imperdiet sit amet, neque. Nam mollis ultrices justo. Sed tempor. Sed vitae tellus. Etiam sem arcu, eleifend sit amet, gravida eget, porta at, wisi. Nam non lacus vitae ipsum viverra pretium. Phasellus massa. Fusce magna sem, gravida in, feugiat ac, molestie eget, wisi. Fusce consectetuer luctus ipsum. Vestibulum nunc. Suspendisse dignissim adipiscing libero. Integer leo. Sed pharetra ligula a dui. Quisque ipsum nibh, ullamcorper eget, pulvinar sed, posuere vitae, nulla. Sed varius nibh ut lacus. Curabitur fringilla. Nunc est ipsum, pretium quis, dapibus sed, varius non, lectus. Proin a quam. Praesent lacinia, eros quis aliquam porttitor, urna lacus volutpat urna, ut fermentum neque mi egestas dolor.Donec placerat. Nullam nibh dolor, blandit sed, fermentum id, imperdiet sit amet, neque. Nam mollis ultrices justo. Sed tempor. Sed vitae tellus. Etiam sem arcu, eleifend sit amet, gravida eget, porta at, wisi. Nam non lacus vitae ipsum viverra pretium. Phasellus massa. Fusce magna sem, gravida in, feugiat ac, molestie eget, wisi. Fusce consectetuer luctus ipsum. Vestibulum nunc. Suspendisse dignissim adipiscing libero. Integer leo. Sed pharetra ligula a dui. Quisque ipsum nibh, ullamcorper eget, pulvinar sed, posuere vitae, nulla. Sed varius nibh ut lacus. Curabitur fringilla. Nunc est ipsum, pretium quis, dapibus sed, varius non, lectus. Proin a quam. Praesent lacinia, eros quis aliquam porttitor, urna lacus volutpat urna, ut fermentum neque mi egestas dolor.
</div>
<div id="right">
Donec placerat. Nullam nibh dolor, blandit sed, fermentum id, imperdiet sit amet, neque. Nam mollis ultrices justo. Sed tempor. Sed vitae tellus. Etiam sem arcu, eleifend sit amet, gravida eget, porta at, wisi. Nam non lacus vitae ipsum viverra pretium. Phasellus massa. Fusce magna sem, gravida in, feugiat ac, molestie eget, wisi. Fusce consectetuer luctus ipsum. amet, gravida eget, porta at, wisi. Nam non 000000000 lacus vitae ipsum viverra pretium. Phasellus massa. Fusce magna sem, gravida in, feugiat ac, molestie eget, wisi. Fusce consectetuer luctus ipsum.
</div>
<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { position: relative; }
#header { width: 100%; height: 100px; background: #f00; margin-bottom: 10px; }
#left { width: 75%; background: #f00; float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; }
#right { width: 20%; background: #00f; float: right; position: relative; right: 0; }
#footer { clear: both; width: 100%; height: 100px; background: #f00; }
```

and finally Javascript:

```
function scrollCheck() {
    var $right = $('#right'),
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        docHeight = $(document).height(),
        rightHeight = $right.height(),
        distanceToTop = rightHeight + 110 - windowHeight,
        distanceToBottom = scrollTop + windowHeight + 110 - docHeight;
    if (scrollTop > distanceToTop) {

        $right.css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'bottom': (scrollTop + windowHeight + 110 > docHeight ? distanceToBottom  + 'px' : '0px')
        });
    }
    else {
        $right.css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'bottom': 'auto'
        });
    }
}

$(window).bind('scroll', scrollCheck);
```

Comment: Thanks Emre,  That almost works, however when I remove the heights of the divs and fill them with content, the sidebar stops at the -40px and does not continue to scroll to the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/pixeljitsu/s3ty9/

Comment: I missed a point. You want right div to anchor bottom. I get it wrong. I'm working on it.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you trying to do but I updated my answer so right div anchors itself bottom of the window until it reaches footer.

Comment: Absolutely perfect!  Thank you so much for this.